# Rails 3 - Factory girl gem - belongs_to and has_one relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have **User** and **Teacher** models. Teacher `belongs_to` User and User `has_one` Teacher. Also i have the code in factory girl file:

```
Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.user_login "Another User"
  user.user_role "admin"
  user.password "foobar"
end

Factory.sequence :user_login do |n|
  "person-#{n}"
end

Factory.define :teacher do |teacher|
  teacher.teacher_last_name   'Last'
  teacher.teacher_first_name  'First'
  teacher.teacher_middle_name 'Middle'
  teacher.teacher_birthday    '01.11.1980'
  teacher.teacher_category    'First category'
  teacher.teacher_sex         'm'
end
```

When i try to create a teacher in my spec:

```
@teacher = Factory(:teacher)
```

Then I recieve the error:

```
Failure/Error: @teacher = Factory(:teacher)
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: User can't be blank
```

As i understand that happens because i don't tell Factory that my teacher `belongs_to` user. How can i fix that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should define association:

```
Factory.define :teacher do |teacher|
  ...
  teacher.user
end
```

Factory Girl has [wonderful tutorial](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md), I recommend you to look at it.

P.S. Why would you want to add those strange prefixes (`user_`, `teacher_`) to model attributes? It looks very ugly, so you definitely do something wrong.

Comment: Agreed that you don't need to prefix column names with `user_` and `teacher_`.